# Is GetType() a method or a class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I came across this code :

```
int myInt = 0;
textBox1.Text = myInt.GetType().Name;
```

According to the [.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.OBJECT.GETTYPE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), GetType() is a method, not a class.

My question is that how am I able to use the dot with a method, like this `GetType().Name`?

Comment: Because it returns an object and objects have properties which you access with the dot syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method can return a class instance, here it´s an instance of the class `Type`. On this object you can access properties, other methods, etc.

Your code could be written as this:

```
int myInt = 0;
Type t = myInt.GetType();
textBox1.Text = t.Name;
```

Maybe it´s easier to understand that way.

Edit:
A method call like `GetType()` executes the method, and everything you do after the `.` applies to the return value of the method, in this case an object of type `Type`.

Comment: thanks for all people that answered the question .this answer stand out however.

Answer (score 5):

`GetType()` is a method that *returns* an instance of a class (in this case, an instance of the [`Type` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

Members of that returned instance of `Type` are accessed via the dot syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Because `GetType()` returns an instance of an object, you can use the dot to access properties or methods of the object that it returns.

Answer (score 2):

The term is commonly know as chaining (certainly in C# and JavaScript) or fluent interface.

So as the other two answers suggested, you are return an instance and executing the methods that are part of that class.

To quote wikipedia:

> In software engineering, a fluent interface (as first coined by Eric Evans and 
>   Martin Fowler) is an implementation of an object oriented API that aims to provide for 
>   more readable code.
>
> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method chaining to relay the instruction > context of a subsequent call (but a fluent interface entails more than just method 
>   chaining). Generally, the context is
>   defined through the return value of a called method
>   self-referential, where the new context is equivalent to the last context
>   terminated through the return of a void context.

Answer (score 2):

From [*`MSDN`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfwy45w9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
Return Value
Type: System.Type
The exact runtime type of the current instance.
```

So basicly, it returns a *class instance*. That's why you can access its properties as well. Let's look at this example;

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine(i.GetType()); // Gets the System.Type of the current instance.
Console.WriteLine(i.GetType().Name); // Gets the name of the current member.
```

Output will be

```
System.Int32
Int32
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/yNG0rn).

On this case, `Name` property is [`MemberInfo.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property. It includes [`System.Reflection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) namespace.

> Gets the name of this member.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) returns the exact runtime type of the `current instance`.

---

Example :

```
using System;

public class MyBaseClass {
}

public class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {
}

public class Test 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      MyBaseClass myBase = new MyBaseClass();
      MyDerivedClass myDerived = new MyDerivedClass();
      object o = myDerived;
      MyBaseClass b = myDerived;

      Console.WriteLine("mybase: Type is {0}", myBase.GetType());
      Console.WriteLine("myDerived: Type is {0}", myDerived.GetType());
      Console.WriteLine("object o = myDerived: Type is {0}", o.GetType());
      Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is {0}", b.GetType());
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//    mybase: Type is MyBaseClass 
//    myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass 
//    object o = myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass 
//    MyBaseClass b = myDerived: Type is MyDerivedClass
```

---

Reference : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because GetType() returns an object, C# language allows you to invoke any member of the object being returned, so your code is a very valid example.

EDIT: Check Jobo's answer to better understand how your code can be written in a more intelligible form

Answer (score 1):

GetType() Gets a Type object that represents the specified type. Type represents class types, interface types, array types, value types, enumeration types, type parameters, generic type definitions. On the type you can access method or property.